# Search content of an array for different value

Tags: arrays

I need to search the content of array if any array member differs from others

I register device IDs in an array and have to chech if any different device is connected? wrong device can be connected any available port. so after I take all IDs, I need check if all are same. maximum 6 devices can be connected at same time. Device IDs will be decided at runtime.

I wrote code below but its not an effective one. also I need wrong device's index which can t be obtained by this code

```
    private byte ArrayCheck(byte[] array) {
        byte buffer=0;
        bool result=false;
        for (byte i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)      
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)                      
                buffer = array[i];
        }

        for (byte i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)  
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)                      
            {
                if (array[i] == buffer)
                    result = true;         
                else
                {
                    result = false;         
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (result)
            return buffer;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

thanks already

Comment: I do not quite get, what this is all about. What ports? In your code you use a byte to iterate the array - are you sure that's sufficient? What exactly do you consider a "wrong" device? Are devices supposed to have the same id or not?

Comment: I just saw: buffer will always be array[array.Length-1] in the second loop. So you are only checking the array against the last array entry.

Comment: Hey fildor let me make it clear. There is a device which you can put 6 slave devices on it. So read all those devices one by one and they tell me their IDs and I put them in an array. to test all 6 devices they have to be same. So after I read all of them I need to check my array if they sent me same ID.

Comment: The method that I have to write must return wrong IDs' index so I can fire a warning for user. I need to decide which device is wrong by majority. For example 4 device sent me 'x' for ID and rest 2 sent 'y' in this case y devices are wrong(if they are 3 to 3 I'm doomed). and order of the devices can be random. (xyxyxx or xxxxyy)

at the beginning it sounds too easy but cases make it impossible to program parametrically.

I hope this time I succeeded to describe clearly

Answer (score 0):

All co-answerers: Mind the comments, they make it clearer.

OOP: The code looks like Java, right?
I would not make comparisons, I'd just count. So you traverse the array just once, building "buckets". You can do it with a Map for instance, where the ids are key and the count are the values. Then you find out the highest count item, remove it from the Map and the remaining keys are your "wrong" ids. Maybe there are more efficient implementations than a map. Perhaps you can even make your own little datastructure, taking an id, counting it and then giving you the "wrong" id list.
That way you can even handle more than 2 different ids.
For the case that two ids have the same count, you'll have to figure out, what the needs of your customers are. Maybe you can just take the "first" one - so it will be more or less random.

Comment: your suggestion enlightens things, but some codes would be really great for the beginning. By the way I'm using c#. As you use see I'm quite good with C but C# is a new thing for me.

Comment: I see. In C# you could use a Dictionary. Maybe Dictionary<Byte,List<Integer>> (I'm not so sure about Types in C#). That way you could just add the id to the list and have the count as list.length ... Haven't got the time for codes, right now, sorry.